# Lifting of Frobenius on semi-abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be a semi-abelian variety over a field $k$($char\, k=p$). Namely, there is an exact sequence of group schemes $$0\to T\to A\to B\to 0$$ where $T$ is a torus, $B$ an abelian variety. Assume that $A$ lifts to $W(k)$.

When it is possible to lift the Frobenius endomorphism of $A$ to $W(k)$?

Probably, $B$ has to be ordinary as only in this case Frobenius endomorphism of $B$ lifts. My problem is that I cannot use obstruction theory here as the existence of liftings on finite levels does not yield to a lifting on the whole $W(k)$.

Maybe some small examples can be done. The case $T=\mathbb{G}_m,\dim B=1$ is already very interesting.

Comment: I assume $k$ is perfect. Let $A'$ be the chosen lift of $A$, giving $B'$ and $T'$ lifting $B$ and $T$ respectively.  Using the canonical link between such extensions and line bundles on $B'$ arising from the dual abelian scheme when $T = {\rm{GL}}_1$ (so we can regard $B'$ as primary and $A'$ as secondary), in general $A'$ corresponds to a $W(k)$-point $\xi$ of ${B'}^{\vee} \otimes {\rm{X}}^{\ast}(T)$ (using the dual abelian scheme).  So the necessary and sufficient condition is that Frobenius of $B$ lifts to $B'$ and its dual map along with Frobenius for $T$ carries $\xi^{(p)}$ to $\xi$.

Comment: What do you mean by `$A$ lifts to $W(k)$'? Do you want the lift to be a scheme or a formal scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[My answer to your other question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/233455/3847) seems to show that if $B$ is ordinary, $A$ has a natural lift over $W$ as a scheme, together with a lift of the Frobenius. I don't see however why the group structure of $A$ should lift, and why it should be compatible with the lift of Frobenius.

**EDIT.** Regarding the group structure: say $B$ is a $T$-torsor over an abelian $A$, trivialized over $0\in A$. We want to give $B$ a group structure such that $p:B\to A$ is a homomorphism with kernel $T$. This should be a map $b:B\times B\to B\to B$ such that the square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
   B\times B @>b>> B \\
 @V{p\times p}VV  @VVpV \\
 A\times A @>a>> A \\
\end{CD}
commutes. This map should factor through a map $b':B\times B\to  B' = a^* B$ from a $T\times T$-torsor $B\times B$ over $A\times A$ to the $T$-torsor $B'$ over $A\times A$, equivariant with respect to the addition map $t:T\times T\to T$. It should be easy to write out explicitly in terms of line bundles corresponding to the torsor $B$ what this map is, and what it should satisfy to give $B$ a group structure, and most probably we will see that this structure is preserved by Teichmueller lifts, so that we get a group structure on the canonical lift.

**EDIT 2.** Some time ago I was pointed in a similar context to look up "bi-extensions" (SGA 7 I, Exp. VII-VIII), but I never did. Perhaps you will find an answer to your question there.